# Component YPbPr to VGA with monitor that supports Sync-on-Green

Tags: video, conversion, monitors, adapter

I want to connect a YPbPr component video signal to a computer monitor using a simple component-to-VGA adapter, I know this isn't possible on most monitors as you would need a converter to convert YPbPr to RGB.

But if the monitor supports Sync-on-Green will it work?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but everything has a green tint and the higher the brightness the less any color but green is visible.

Using a sony trinitron.